# Is it possible to outsource calculations of an app to an external server?

Tags: outsourcing

I have a general question and unfortunately no background in programming apps, so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question:

If my app has to process difficult calculations for which the power of the phone or tablet would not be enough, would it be possible to outsource these calculations to an external server? 
And if this is already done in some apps, could you give me examples?

I have done some research but did not find anything... probably I have searched with the wrong terms.

Comment: Yes you could - the simplest solution is a simple HTTP API that takes the calculation parameters and returns the result. Or returns a job ID which can later be passed to another method which returns the status and/or results of the job.

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260) See also [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible. The question whether it's a good idea depends on how *strong* the pressures you're experiencing are.

- The slower your mobile processor is, the more sense it makes to outsorce computation.
- The faster your remote link is, the more sense it makes.
- The more sensitive the processed data are, the less appropriate it is.
- The more repeatable (i.e. cacheable) the input/output combinations are, the less sense it makes. (In the extreme case you might compute a value once and then never need any other!)

Comment: +1, but would add that I don't know of any existing ways to do this, particularly in android. If you can't find a library to facilitate this, build what you need yourself (maybe use JMS if appropriate).